# How can I prove $|a_{m+1}-a_{m+2}+a_{m+3}-...\pm a_{n}| \le |a_{m+1}|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Give a sequence $(a_n)$ that satisfying:

(i) the sequence is decreasing: $$a_n \ge a_{n+1} \forall n \in \mathbb N$$
(ii) the sequence is converging to $0$: $$(a_n) \rightarrow 0$$

**Problem**:Prove that $|a_{m+1}-a_{m+2}+a_{m+3}-...\pm a_{n}| \le |a_{m+1}|$ $\forall n \gt m \ge N$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$

I think we shall do this by induction. Let $n=1$, then clearly $|a_{m+1}| \le |a_{m+1}|$. Suppose $n=k$ holds true, then for $n=k+1$,
$|a_{m+1}-a_{m+2}+a_{m+3}-...\pm a_{m+k} \mp a_{m+k+1}|$ ...

For the step $n=k+1$, I give up(the triangle inequality will not work!). So, how do we continue to do this? I have a strange feeling that I have made a big mistake somewhere because this induction is really weird. Please help me proceed with how to prove this strange inequality. I thank you very much.

Note: every term in this sequence MUST BE positive(proven).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an induction form of the previous answer:

---

We will show that $0\le a_{m+1}-a_{m+2}+a_{m+3}-\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}a_{m+k}\le a_{m+1}$

for all integers $k\ge1 \text{ and } m\ge0$ by induction on $k$:

1) This is valid for $k=1$, since $0\le a_{m+1}\le a_{m+1}$.

2) Assume this is valid for all integers $l$ with $1\le l\le k$.

a)  If k is even, then

i) $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}+a_{m+k+1}\ge0$ and

ii) $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}=a_{m+1}-\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}\le a_{m+1}$  $\;$since $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}\ge 0$

b)  If k is odd, then

i) $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}+(a_{m+k}-a_{m+k+1})\ge0$ and

ii) $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}-a_{m+k+1}\le \sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^{i-1}a_{m+i}\le a_{m+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Let us write $n=m+p$, so that the sum has $p$ elements. We prove that

$$\left| a_{m+1}-a_{m+2} +\cdots \pm  a_{m+p} \right| \leq |a_{m+1}|=a_{m+1} \tag{1} $$ for all $m,p$:

First note that the $\pm$ actually equals $(+)$ if $p$ is odd, and is $(-)$ if $p$ is even. This motivates breaking the proof into two cases:

1. If $p=2k+1$ is odd, summing the inequalities $a_{m+2l+1}-a_{m+2l+2} \geq 0$ from $l=0$ to $k-1$, shows that we can take the absolute value in $(1)$ off, as both expressions
   $$(a_{m+1}-a_{m+2})+(a_{m+3}-a_{m+4})+ \cdots (a_{m+p-2}-a_{m+p-1}) $$
   and
   $$a_{m+p} $$
   are nonnegative in that case. Once the absolute value is gone, it's easy to see that $(1)$ holds by considering both expressions above again.
2. If $p=2k$ is even, we can similarly break the sum into a sum of nonnegative summands, which allows us to take the absolute value off. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hmm...I really appreciate the answer. However, we do not know if the inequality continues to hold with every $n \in \mathbb N$, that is why induction is our best bet here. Your solution only suggests that the sum is non-negative, unfortunately.(at least that is what I understand)

Comment: Note that you wrote $a_n \geq a_{n+1} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. If you rearrange this, you find that the inequalities in the answer always hold.

Comment: Ok, I see now why the inequality works. But is there anyway to prove it based on the n=k+1 arguments ? This does not look like an acceptable induction argument. (although the solution is ok)

Comment: @SONTO I'm sorry, but I can't find a proof by induction of this result.

Comment: no problem my friend. You helped me a lot and I appreciate it so much.